# Incorrect Url.Action when URL rewrite is used

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting, asp.net-mvc-routing

I get an incorrect URL from the `Action` method when I use a URL rewrite.

I have this rewrite rule in web.config:

```
<rule name="Old Objects 2" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^transportbilar/(nya|begagnade|miljobilar)/(.*)$" ignoreCase="true"/>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="/transportbilar/{R:2}"/>
</rule>
```

This will rewrite an URL like `/transportbilar/nya/fiat/7s76s8dg` to `/transportbilar/fiat/7s76s8dg`, which works fine, but the `Url.Action` gets confused by this.

I use an expression like this to create an URL in the page:

```
url.Action("Slideshow", "Object", new { id = objectId });
```

When the URL rewrite is not used (browsing directly to the page), this produces the correct URL `/Object/Slideshow/7s76s8dg`, but when the URL rewrite is used, the `Action` method adds the first part of the page URL to the generated URL, and produces the incorrect URL `/transportbilar/Object/Slideshow/7s76s8dg`.

I think that I can do a Redirect in the rewrite rule instead, which would circumvent the problem as the requesting URL would change, but is there a way to make it work without changing it to a Redirect?

#### Edit:

The routes that I think could possibly be relevant are these (added in this order):

```
transportbilar/handlare/{id}/{criteria}
transportbilar/handlare
transportbilar
transportbilar/sokresultat/{criteria}
transportbilar/{brand}/{id}/{criteria}
{controller}/{action}/{id}
```

The last route would catch the url `/Object/Slideshow/7s76s8dg` and the second from last would catch `/transportbilar/fiat/7s76s8dg`.

Comment: Is transportbilar a virtual directory?

Comment: What Routes do you have set up? Also, since you are using MVC, you should probably using routes rather than the IIS rewriting module. You'll run into more problems if you need to do user authentication. Have a look at http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/496/iis-url-rewriting-and-aspnet-routing/

Comment: @diamandiev: No, it's not a directory at all, it's part of a route.

Comment: @Musaul: I have added the routes that I think possibly could affect this above.

Answer (score 5):

Hmmm.. don't think I can help you get to your rewrite based solution. I'm guessing internally IIS/ASP.NET may be having a problem that you may face when you try to hack a regex mapping in your routes - i.e. `URL.Action` can't determine the correct reverse mapping from the Controller/Action combination.

You could check what the following say about your URL, and if that gives you any hints as to what the problem is ...

```
<%= Request.Path %>
<%= Request.RawUrl %>
<%= Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_URL"] %>
```

... to see if `/transportbilar' is being added that stage.

In any case, I'd seriously go with redirecting the legacy URLs. That approach isolates your actual current system from the legacy, especially since it seems like your route collection is complicated enough already.

Comment: I put those in the page, and the RawUrl contains the original URL, and the other contain the rewritten URL. Is this a bug in IIS? What do you mean by "hack a regex mapping"?

Comment: So it looks like its the *rewriter* that's changing `/Object/Slideshow/7s76s8dg` to `/transportbilar/Object/Slideshow/7s76s8dg`. I'd try to isolate that rule and try it in a separate context/website with similar URLs to see if the problem can be replicated there.

Comment: Regex routes ... http://www.iridescence.no/post/Outbound-Urls-with-Regular-Expression-Routes.aspx

Comment: @Musaul: No, it's not the rewriter that changes the URL, that's the URL that is produced by the `Action` method. It's the route `{controller}/{action}/{id}` that is used to create the URL, as that is the only route to use the controller and action in the URL. I'm not using any regular expressions in the routes.

Comment: The URLs in the request object should not be affected by `url.action`, they are set on the incoming request before mvc starts handling the request. They are, however, affected by the rewrite module. If that's already happened by that stage, mvc could well be seeing the wrong url, and mapping it to a different controller.

Comment: @Musaul: The URL is already wrong when it's created by the Action method, before it's used to request anything.

Comment: OK ... in your current application in the page that would be displayed as a result of typing in `http://<your_site>//Object/Slideshow/7s76s8dg`, add the above url displaying code. ... Browse to that page, and please let us know what three URLs are displayed. - All of this happens with no regard to what `url.action` thinks the URL should be for a given controller. - The reason I'm asking for this is that, if ANY of them show `/transportbilar` then your rewriting is breaking things, and unexpected things will happen from this point forward including routing, and building URLS using `url.action`.

Comment: @Musaul: The slideshow page is irrelevant, it's the URL to that page that is wrong. It should always be the same, regardless of whether I got to the page containing the link through a rewrite or not.

Answer (score 3):

Use routing instead of URL rewrites, you are using MVC after all.

Check this article about routing:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/03/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-2-url-routing.aspx

Comment: I am already using routes, and if I add this as a route also, they conflict. Depending on the order I add them, the `Action` method will produce the URL `/transportbilar/nya/fiat/7s76s8dg` when I want `/transportbilar/fiat/7s76s8dg`, or the URL `/transportbilar/nya/fiat/7s76s8dg` will be misinterpreded so that I end up with the id `fiat` instead of `7s76s8dg`.

Comment: Remove the URL rewrite and ONLY use the route. I can't see why that wouldn't work. Controller=transportbilar    Action=fiat   Id=7s76s8dg

Comment: Can't you create multiple routes like this? ... `/transportbilar/nya/{action}/{id}`, `/transportbilar/begagnade/{action}/{id}` and have them all handled by the same controller? ... or are you trying to use the url rewrite as a shorthand?

Comment: That doesn't work because I want to handle both `/transportbilar/nya/fiat/7s76s8dg` and `/transportbilar/fiat/7s76s8dg`.

Comment: @Musaul: If the routes followed the same pattern, it would be no problem, and I already have multiple routes similar to that. The problem is that I have the older version of the URLs with `nya`/`begagnade` in them, and the new version without that distinction.

Answer (score 3):

Is the Url rewriting stuff for legacy Urls?

Could you perhaps ditch the Url rewrite and using a route with constraints. Something like:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "OldObject2",
    "transportbilar/{mycondition}/{make}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Object", action = "Slideshow" },
    new
    {
        mycondition = "nya|begagnade|miljobila"
    }
);
```

I'm not sure exactly what your app is doing so the above might not make 100% sense but should give you an idea of what I'm thinking...

Comment: I have already tried that, but with three separate routes. The problem with that is that it doesn't work to have both routes like `transportbilar/nya/{make}/{id}` and `transportbilar/{make}/{id}`. Depending on the order they are added, either the route mapping or the Action method uses the wrong route to decode/encode an URL.

Comment: @Guffa, why don't you make the `{mycondition}` be optional ?

Comment: @Gaby aka G. Petrioli: I tried that, and neither resolving the URL or mathing the action worked.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me (borrowing a little from another answer):

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "NewRoute",
    "transportbilar/{make}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Test" }
);
routes.MapRoute(
    "OldRoute",
    "transportbilar/{mycondition}/{make}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Test" },
    new
    {
        mycondition = "nya|begagnade|miljobila"
    }
);
```

The new one goes first so the helper methods resolve to it. But both go to the same controller and action.

```
<p>@Html.ActionLink("link", "Test", new { make = "testmake4", id = 5})</p>
```

On both the old and new URLs this resolves to `/transportbilar/testmake4/5`

Comment: Thanks for the effort to test it. I have tried that (before and now once more), and both URLs resolve to the first route. It probably works in your test because getting make="nya" and id="testmarke4" doesn't cause an error, but I get an error when the make is sent to the id parameter in the controller method and it can't be parsed.

Comment: Make sure you haven't marked the id parameter as optional. That might cause it to match the wrong rule.

Comment: Also just double checked and the values are coming through correctly in both cases. (MVC 3)

Answer (score 0):

You can use your these functions to avoid these problems:

```
    public static string UrlAction(string actionName) {
        return String.Format("/{0}", actionName);
    }

    public static string UrlAction(string actionName, string controllerName) {
        return String.Format("/{0}/{1}", controllerName, actionName);
    }

    public static string UrlAction(string actionName, string controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues) {
        string url = String.Format("/{0}/{1}", controllerName, actionName);

        var parameters = routeValues.Select(s => string.Format("{0}={1}", s.Key, s.Value))
            .Aggregate((current, next) => string.Format("{0}&{1}", current, next));

        return url+"?"+parameters;
    }
```